# Ways of passing arguments - value vs reference vs pointer?

Tags: c++

In contrast to other programming languages, C++ supports three different kinds of parameter passing:

- by value
- by reference
- by address

I am programming for a long time with C# and from the point of view from as a C# developer, C++ confuses me. In C# it is fairly easy. Just define what you want and return the result whereas C++ is much more sophisticated. Is there something like an guideline when to use `by value`, `by reference`, `or by address`?

Comment: C# IMHO could be confusing as well. structs are passed by value and classes by reference unless otherwise specified

Comment: There are several guides on this elsewhere. Understanding what each does is the key.

Comment: "by address" is actually "by value". See the wikipedia [Evaluation Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) article.

Comment: "by address" is really just a subset of "by value".  The value that you're passing happens to be an address (i.e., a pointer value).

Comment: @AusCBloke This is actually the only way to get all the misconceptions out of his head. Your comments about "implicit pointer" are wrong and achieve exactly the opposite.

Comment: @pmr: I removed that comment because it was pretty dodgey. The way *I* look at it though, a reference is *kind of* like an implicit pointer. This is why he should read a book/guide.

Comment: by adress/ reference are used to be ale to modify the parameter. the modification will be still present after the end of the function. but by value : the parameter is copied and the function uses thatcopy, so if you chane the paramete inside the unction, no modification will be kept ater the end of the function.

Comment: I can't understand why people think this is "not constructive"; it's a question about basic programming technique, and ought to be answerable in a fairly objective way. The ability to pass parameters in these various ways exists for a reason, and it seems odd to me to brush new programmers off when they try to figure out what those reasons actually are - even if there are times when a trade-off has to be made.

Comment: Coming from C# you should be able to understand them, as C# has more *modes*: a function can take an integer by value (default) or by reference `void f( ref int x )` (in C# there is an additional `out`). As of pointers, you can think of C# reference types as types that must be managed through pointers (a C# reference is a C++ pointer without pointer arithmetic)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference between passing by reference and passing by value is pretty important. When you pass by value, you're really passing a *copy* of the value in question. No matter what happens in the function, the value in the caller will remain unchanged. So, say you've got a function that adds one to an `int` and returns an `int`:

```
int addOne(int theNumber)
{
    theNumber += 1;
    return theNumber;
}
```

Here, you're passing by value. You'd call it like this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = addOne(a);    // b gets 11, but a remains the same
```

If you want to pass by reference instead, the function would look like this:

```
int addOne(int &theNumber)
{
    theNumber += 1;
    return theNumber;
}
```

Note that the body of the function stays the same. Again, you call it like this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = addOne(a);    // b gets 11, but this time a is also changed to 11.
```

The big difference here is that you're passing a *reference* to `a`. It's really a sort of implicit pointer to `a`, but you can think of it as passing `a` itself. Since you're passing `a` instead of copy of the value of `a`, `a` itself will actually be changed by the function.

The third way, passing the address, looks like this:

```
int addOne(int *theNumber)
{
    *theNumber = *theNumber + 1;
    return *theNumber;
}
```

This does the same thing as the reference version, but the pointer here is explicit. You use it like this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = addOne(&a);    // b gets 11, but this time a is also changed to 11.
```

So, in this case you're explicitly passing the address of `a`, which is to say a pointer to `a`. If you're used to passing by value only, this should be familiar. This is how you pass `a` by reference in C and some other C-like languages. It works fine, but you have to do all the pointer stuff yourself. C++ adds the concept of passing by reference to the language to make this all easier.

A final possibility is to pass a *const reference*, which avoids copying the value, but prohibits changing it in the called function. If a function takes a const reference, you can read that as a promise not to change the parameter (and it's a promise that the compiler will enforce). This is particularly useful if the value is more than a few bytes, so that it's desirable to avoid copying the value if you can. Objects are often passed by const reference for this reason.

So, as a guideline, pass by value or const reference when you don't want the thing the caller is passing to change. Pass by reference when you do want it to change. And don't pass by pointer unless you're dealing with a C library or other code that requires it.

Answer (score 1):

passing parameter by value makes a copy of that parameter which will be used inside the function. the modifications of the parameter will be lost after tjhe end of the function :

e.g. :

```
void f(int a);
[
    a = 25;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    f(i);
    cout<<i;   //the printed   value will be 10;
}
```

but if you use adress or reference, it is different :

```
void g(int &a)
{
    a = 25;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    g(i);
    cout<<i;  // the printed value is 25 

}
```

an advantage of passing parameter by adress or reference isthat the parameter will not be entirely copied to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

It's more confusing / complicated when you're passing objects that you yourself have defined or those in other libraries. A dependency-limiting issue is you can forward declare a class without actually including the header, like:

```
 // #include "myclass.h"   // we **Don't** include it! Less code-bloat
 class MyClass;  // foward-declare it

 void MyFunction(  MyClass*  obj  ); 
 // good to go, define this in .cpp file. 
 // someone including **This** header won't have to include myclass.h

 void MyFunction( MyClass& obj ); // Not Legal! 
 void MyFunction( MyClass obj ); // Not Legal! 
 void MyFunction( const MyClass& obj ); // Not Legal!
```

I try to use the "const MyClass& obj" convention but sometimes it is not possible because a library prevents this mode. If you're getting started, I suggest you pass things like 'int', 'double' by value and don't worry about it. Pass standard-template objects that should *not change* as 'const std::Class& var', and have your functions return things instead of modifying by reference.

When your code does what you want and you worry about performance, or a library you use requires it, re-think the approach.